# Race condition occured while using two tableviews and app crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, race-condition

I am using a tab bar with two buttons on a uiview controller to show two different tableview. Everything works fine if used normally.

but the problem arises when i scroll one tableview and and instantly click the button to switch to second tableview.

I guess due to race condition occor as one tableview doesnt complete its process and i started the second process.

Is there any solution to this problem.

```
@IBOutlet var tableViewCase: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var tableViewInsp: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var tabBar: UITabBar!

var selectedTableView:UITableView!

func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem)
{
    if item.tag == TAB_BAR_CASES {
        app?.settings.lastSelectedInboxTab = ACTIVITY_KIND_CASE
        selectedTableView = tableViewCase
        presenter.refresh()

        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: tableViewCase)
        showSelectedTableView()
    }
    else if item.tag == TAB_BAR_INSP {
        app?.settings.lastSelectedInboxTab = ACTIVITY_KIND_INSP
        selectedTableView = tableViewInsp

        presenter.refresh()

        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: tableViewInsp)
        showSelectedTableView()
    }
    refreshTable(selectedTableView)
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to this question.

Comment: It happens because you are changing data source array  while scrolling is ongoing so it will try to access datasource array in cell for row, which causes a crash

Comment: @jon Snow. Yes exectly this is happening right now. Is there any solution to handle this situation.

Comment: @joern i updated question with some code. Tell me if you need anything else.

Comment: @ParvBhasker https://stackoverflow.com/q/2318445/4601900

Comment: Most likely you're not handling your data source properly. Check @NeverHopeless answer. But also I'd suggest you to hide or show your tableviews with `tableView.isHidden = true // or false`, instead of bring subview to front.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible when in UITableView's delegate functions you don't handle based on tableView's instance. For example, handling like this should help:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  if(tableView == myTableView1) {
    return myTableview1DataSourceRowCountVariable
  }
  else if(tableView == myTableView2) {
    return myTableview2DataSourceRowCountVariable
  }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
  if(tableView == myTableView1) {
    return myTableview1SectionCountVariable
  }
  else if(tableView == myTableView2) {
    return myTableview2SectionCountVariable
  }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  if(tableView == myTableView1) {
    return PrepareMyCellForTableView1()
  }
  else if(tableView == myTableView2) {
    return PrepareMyCellForTableView2()
  }
}
```

This way before proceeding, it will first recognise *on which table view*, *with which data source* and *on which index* it is working on.